# Nginx Reverse proxy issue in Azure App Service

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, azure-web-apps, azure-app-services

I've been struggling for a few weeks now with an issue and I'm not knowledgeable enough to even know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible. FusionAuth forums haven't been very helpful, and neither has Azure support which can't do much outside of App service configuration help.

To give a brief explanation of what I am trying to achieve. I have FusionAuth running in an App Service Linux container. It has a domain similar like https://mycustomapp.azurewebsites.net, but I setup a custom domain https://auth.mycustomapp.com.

FusionAuth by default is listening on port 9011 within it's container. This is the http port. When run in production I receive this warning:

[image]

The recommended solution for this by FusionAuth is to have a reverse proxy sitting in front of the app to add the correct request header.

I've been trying to configure a Nginx reverse proxy in another App Service Linux instance in the same App Service plan. The container is using nginx:latest, and I'm copying into the container my custom config file as well as ssl certificates. I also setup a custom domain for this app, running at proxy.mycustomapp.com.

My configuration looks something like this:

```
server {
    if ($host = proxy.mycustomapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name proxy.mycustomapp.com;
    return 404;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name proxy.mycustomapp.com;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/mycustomapp.com.log;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/auth.mycustomapp.com-chain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/auth.mycustomapp.com-key.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_read_timeout      90;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;

    proxy_pass https://mycustomapp.azurewebsites.net/;
  }
}
```

My nginx server starts without issue but when navigating to proxy.mydomain.com I get a browser error that the page redirected me too many times.

[image]

Firstly is what I am trying to do possible, and if so what is wrong with my config?

Comment: Running `curl -i <your_url> | grep -i location` might give you more insight. Thus looks fot  Location headers in the response. If you see a series of redirects, you might have a redirection loop.. You can also use the developer tools in your browser and then the network tab

Comment: The curl command doesn't seem to show anything wrong. The network tab shows consecutive redirects of the same page with status 301 each time I load the page. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Why do you have `listen 0.0.0.0:80` in the http block? Anything relevant in your access log?

Comment: I think it can be substituted for listen 80. In any case I figured out the issue. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pulling my hair out for 3 weeks I just figured it out. There are two issues at play here.

1. Azure App service TLS/SSL requests never get to the app. They are terminated at the front end. This explains why only the server block listening on 80 was being hit, and not the other server block.

   - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux&tabs=debian#detect-https-session
2. Since I am proxying to an external host, I needed to replace ***proxy_set_header Host $host;*** with ***proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;***

Considering these points, I can remove the server block listening on 443 and just keep the one listening on 80. My final code looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name proxy.mycustomapp.com;

  location / {
      proxy_set_header        Host $proxy_host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port '443';
      
      proxy_pass https://mycustomapp.azurewebsites.net/;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah if you want to reverse proxy in Azure an application gateway is a better choice

Comment: I looked into it but decided to go this route for cost reasons. Out of curiosity are there downsides to using App service as a reverse proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I think your http block is incorrect, try this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name proxy.mycustomapp.com;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```